# How to increase interview calls from the recruiter?

Tags: interviewing, new-job

I am a fresher and completed the following:

B.E(CS) june 2014 pass out.
Java/J2EE course in an institute.
Oracle Associate Level Java Certification 1Z0-803 (pursuing).
Have 2 months of work expereience in HTML, CSS, JavaScript

What more can I do in java domain and put it in my resume to increase calls for interview from recruiters in java domain? Please tell why you recommended that.

Or the above is enough to get more calls from recruiters in java domain? if so, can you please explain why?

Please reply am in need of a job in java domain.

Comment: Don't rely too much on recruiters, and instead apply for jobs yourself - if your looking to put stuff on your resume, make sure you are working on stuff while searching for a job - your personal website, open source software, etc. are all good things. Also since you have recently graduated, ask your professors - they are likely to have connections in the industry and be willing to help you (not to mention you should be talking with them anyways, as they will most likely be your main references for a first job).

Comment: Thank you. What about online job portals. I can upload my resume there also to get more job interviews right?

Comment: jobs and interviews depend on quality, not quantity - if you aren't researching the company/position and tailoring your resume to it, chances are it won't even get looked at, which is what I think of when I hear "online job portals" - that and desperation. I would say it's exceedingly rare for anyone to get a "good" job from such a service, but I suppose it's not impossible - but you would also get tons of spam from doing such things as well, so I would avoid it as best I can (employers don't particularly like desperate new hires either..)

Comment: Then which service can I use to get interview calls for the job or just to get a job? (other than college professors )

Comment: Job/career fairs where you get to talk to people would be a good place to start.. but do your own research and find out which companies need java developers - there isn't any easy service that will do it for you.

Comment: @user2813274, I think you gave a good answer in your chain of comments above - why don't you turn them into a proper answer? Then it can even get upvoted and accepted :-)

Comment: Recruitment companies are a business.  They are focused on making money for *themselves*, not you.

Answer (score 1):

Calls from recruiters and even interviews are not the same as job offers.

You need to be applying for jobs yourself too; work on customising your resume to each employer and think about how to show that you really do meet their needs and differentiate yourself from all the other recent graduates who want work as Java programmers.

Do you contribute to open source projects? Do you have any projects on your resume that might interest someone? Getting involved in things like this also increase your 'networking opportunities' too. It's just possible that you could end up speaking to someone on a project like this whose full time employer is looking for someone with your skills.

Your question gives the impression that you think that getting a job is a numbers game, that if you get enough phone calls from recruiters then you'll get *x%* of them turn into interviews and then *y%* of *those* will turn into job offers. That isn't the case at all.

There's no magic "get lots of job interviews with this one weird trick" hack that everyone except you knows about. It's perfectly possible to have 100 interviews as a poorly prepared candidate and never get a job and equally possible to prepare well and land a good job with your first interview. Finding a job is less about getting lots of chances and more about making the most of the chances you get.

Answer (score 1):

1. Being fresh out of school, you don't have many industry connections yet, so you should rely on what you do have - your school and professors. See if your school has any sort of job/career fair, and attend it to get an idea of what companies are looking for and perhaps find a couple you are interested in. Also reach out to your professors while they still remember you - they are likely to have connections with professionals in the field and can help get you acquainted. You should talk with your professors anyways as they will be your primary source of references, and may even have an in-department job for you.
2. Don't rely on recruiters - those are hired by companies to work for companies, and thus they don't work for you - now it may happen that there is a shared interest, however don't count on it and do your own work. The recruiters don't care if you need to have a roof over your head or not, they care about their own roof first. Similarly websites that send your resume to multiple companies are almost never a good fit due to similar reasons.
3. Good jobs require effort - both on the companies part and your own - it would be exceedingly rare for you to find a good job without researching the company/position (miracles can happen, but again, don't rely on them) - as such, companies don't always get the perfect candidate, but they do have more options to choose from, and will simply ignore anyone who doesn't even tailor their resume to their needs. This means that there it is inherently impossible for any "mass application" to work (this includes "online job portals" and similar where you upload a single resume and don't know which companies you applied to, or most recruiting agencies). There are also down-sides from the mentioned approaches, mainly spam - which is quite common with such sites that allow non-serious entities to view the contact information.

To touch on a few more points:
"more calls" - this is highly subjective, more than what? the unknown amount that you currently receive? - and again, this is about quality, not quantity - it doesn't matter how many call you if none can get you a job.

"what can I do" - keep busy - do you have a personal web-site? I would certainly expect someone with html/css/javascript experience to have one - this does not need to be a paid site, but a sample portfolio with school projects/etc. would be normal for the field. I also strongly suggest contributing to open source software, as there you will gain experience working with larger projects and groups of people, something that a personal website may not represent.
There are also "Hackathons" that you can attend (again, likely to be run by a school) where you can go meet and code with other developers - there are also usually representatives from tech companies that are looking to hire anyone who stands out in particular.